# how to set maintenance mode for entire website with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, offline, maintenance-mode

i have found this code for htaccess to disable the entire website (for maintenance mode):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/offline.php$
RewriteRule .* /offline.php [R=307,L]
```

Now in my offline.php page i have a link to css and js files, like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="include/css/error.css">
<script src="include/js/file.js"></script>
```

when i use the code above to set the maintenance mode, the offline.php page is loaded, but without the css and js, how can i allow the loading of these 2 files?

and i think that is useful to disable the website for everyone except my ip, in this way i can update the website, is that possibile?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i find out an blog that contains answer for your question please check this [site](https://web.archive.org/web/20111110144604/https://nocreativity.com/blog/how-to-create-a-maintenance-mode-with-htaccess/)

The below examples are taken from the above mentioned site.

> If you don’t already have an .htaccess file in the root of your
> domain, create one and add the following code. If you already have an
> .htaccess file, add the following code in front of everything that
> might be in there

```
RewriteEngine On

# Add all the IP addresses of people that are helping in development
# and need to be able to get past the maintenance mode.
# One might call this the 'allow people list'
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^83\.101\.79\.62
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^91\.181\.207\.191

# Make sure the maintenance mode only applies to this domain
# Example: I am hosting different sites on my server
# which could be affected by these rules.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^nocreativity.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.nocreativity.com$

# This is the 'ignore file list'. It allows access to all
# files that are needed to display the maintenance mode page.
# Example: pages, css files, js files, images, anything.
# IMPORTANT: If you don't do this properly, visitors will end up with
# endless redirect loops in their browser.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/offline\.htm$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/css\/style\.css$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/images\/logo\.png$

# Rewrite whatever request is coming in to the maintenance mode page
# The R=302 tells browsers (and search engines) that this
# redirect is only temporarily.
# L stops any other rules below this from executing whenever somebody is redirected.
RewriteRule \.*$ /offline.htm [R=302,L]
```

Comment: your link is 404.  not sure if that was a joke

Comment: @Jon i have added the same site content in the answer. Please check. and thank you for the update.

Answer (score 2):

That's a great answer but here's the code from it in case the link ever dies:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Add all the IP addresses of people that are helping in development
# and need to be able to get past the maintenance mode.
# One might call this the 'allow people list'
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^83\.101\.79\.62
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^91\.181\.207\.191

# Make sure the maintenance mode only applies to this domain
# Example: I am hosting different sites on my server
# which could be affected by these rules.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^nocreativity.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.nocreativity.com$

# This is the 'ignore file list'. It allows access to all
# files that are needed to display the maintenance mode page.
# Example: pages, css files, js files, images, anything.
# IMPORTANT: If you don't do this properly, visitors will end up with
# endless redirect loops in their browser.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/offline\.htm$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/css\/style\.css$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/images\/logo\.png$

# Rewrite whatever request is coming in to the maintenance mode page
# The R=302 tells browsers (and search engines) that this
# redirect is only temporarily.
# L stops any other rules below this from executing whenever somebody is redirected.
RewriteRule \.*$ /offline.htm [R=302,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Step1: create a file'.maintence' in the root directory like .htaccess

Step2: put this code in the file

```
  <?php $upgrading = time();?>
```

Step3:Save the file.then you can see the default maintance message'Briefly unavailable for scheduled maintenance. Check back in a minute.'.

If you want to have your own warning message do below:

Create a 'maintenance.php' file and placing it in your wp-content directory, wordpress uses this file to display during any forced maintenance period that you set.